# Checking that an element matches a selector

Tags: javascript

I've created a method from [Mozilla's polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches#Polyfill) to check if an element matches a selector:

```
function matches(elm, selector) {
    var el = angular.element(elm)[0];
    var matches = (el.document || el.ownerDocument).querySelectorAll(selector),
        i = matches.length;
    while (--i >= 0 && matches.item(i) !== el) ;
    return i > -1;
}
```

This is fine for ids, classes, etc, but doesn't seem to work with tags, see screenshot:

[image]

You can see that the element does indeed match the selector, but the function returns false. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why can't you use the standard `Element#matches`? Just wondering.

Comment: Browser compatibility I'm afraid.

Comment: Have you tried different browsers? if you examine the `matches` list, what do you see? Are iframes involved by any chance?

Comment: What is the meaning of `angular.element(elm)[0]`? What happens if you change that line to `var el = elm;`?

Comment: @torazaburo - it's the same result. That is to normalize it so that it can handle both DOM elements and Angular elements.